# Excel Cells to ADODB.Recordset

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, adodb, recordset

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I want to make into an `ADODB.Recordset`. I've done this with an Excel table before, but not just cells. The `Fields` are in row 4 while the `Values` are in row 5. Everything before and after that is just visual garbage such as Title etc.

Normally I would just do something like `getSomething = MyADO.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [Worksheet$]")`, but I'm lost on what to do here and how to test that it works.

Comment: You can use a specific range if you know what it is:
E.g. `getSomething = MyADO.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [Worksheet$A4:F5]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (testing with ADO in Excel VBA tho...)

```
getSomething = MyADO.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [Worksheet$4:5]")
```

Answer (score 1):

consider using EEPlus to manipulate the excel object model.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/